# Как лучше выразиться?

Tags: грамотная-речь

(о том, что свойственно человеку). Хвост по физкультуре - это не удивительно. Слово "не удивительно" не совсем подходит.

Здесь оно употреблено в отриц. смысле, поэтому отделяется от "не"?

Answer (score 1):

1) Возможны два варианта:

Хвост по физкультуре — это **не удивительно.** НЕ — отрицательная частица.

Хвост по физкультуре — это **неудивительно** (=обычно). НЕ — приставка. Утвердительное значение, возможна замена близким синонимом.

2) Можно написать так:  ***Хвост по физкультуре — это не удивляет (обычное дело, в порядке вещей).***

Comment: Мне важно найти выражение, синанимичное "Это вполне в моем духе", "Это вполне в моем репертуаре". Меня укоряют: "У тебя хвост. Как ты мог его заработать?" Я должен сказать что-то, рассеивающее удивление порицающего, констатировать репертуарность такого события.

Comment: Напишите: Хвост по физкультуре — это для меня нормально,  обычное дело, в порядке вещей.